# Aligning Image in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, alignment

I have an image in the css, but I want to add a link to that image so I pulled it out of the css and inserted directly in the HTML with an anchor tag.

I am having trouble aligning the image to the top left of the div class.

```
<div class="logoHeader" style="height:125px; width:900px" >
    <a href="http://www.abc123.com/">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" style="position:relative;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I've tried adding

```
style="padding-top:0px; padding-left:0px;"
```

but the image is floating instead of being in the top left corner.

Any thoughts on how to get the image to align to the top left corner via the HTML?

The div tag css is:

```
.logoHeader {padding:45px 20px 0px 20px;}
```

Comment: Using something like firebug or chromes "inspect element" will help immensely in solving these issues.  You can literally hover over dom elements and see what padding and margins are applied

Comment: you want to stick to topmost left most corner?

Comment: Padding is not positioning.  Also, you did not say where you tried adding that.

Comment: @blasteralfred in the topmost left most corner of the div. not the page

Comment: @user630581 check my answer. I used your div to position the image. Its in the div. You may use the margin attributes of div to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **padding** is causing it to **float**, it's conforming to the rules you set (have a margin of 45px), if you want it in the top left corner:

See http://jsfiddle.net/9KJA7/ for an example

```
/* Ignore */
.logoHeader {background-color: red}
img {height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green}

/* Your code */
.logoHeader {padding:45px 20px 0px 20px; position: relative}
​img {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding set on .logoHeader will prevent the image from hitting the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for;

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/pZZ5L/)*** is the Live demo. Or do you want ***[this](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/pZZ5L/1/)***?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the image to stay **fixed** all the time? In that case, remove the padding and  use this:

```
.logoHeader {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 5; padding: 0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u8k6/

Check your code: http://jsfiddle.net/3u8k6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with position absolute on the img tag, like this:

```
<div class="logoHeader" style="height:125px; width:900px; position: relative" ><a href="http://www.abc123.com/"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" /></a></div>
```

To make use of position absolute in the image, your div must be position relative. I hope this helps.